# last digits invisible from call history

Tags: call-history, sony-xperia

I have recently bought Sony Xperia and recently have been facing this weird problem.
The last 2 digits of the phone number in call history are invisible. And this is not the case for whole history, but only for some.
Please guide if you know reason/resolution for the same.

Comment: Which Xperia phone are you using specifically? (like Xperia Z,Z1,Z2,J,T,S,P,U etc) and a screen shot is helpful.

Comment: You could download a different dialer application. Check out the play store, or a diffent call log app and so on. Might be the easiest option.